# Untyped / typeless parameters in Delphi

Tags: delphi, parameters, typing

What type are parameters without type like in the class TStringStream:

```
function Read(var Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; override;
```

What is the type of Buffer parameter (is it a type of Pointer ?).

Answer (score 25):

I wrote an article about this very topic a few years ago:

> [What is an untyped parameter?](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/untyped)

Untyped parameters are used in a few situations; the `TStream.Read` method you ask about most closely matches with the `Move` procedure I wrote about. Here's an excerpt:

> ```
> procedure Move(const Source; var Dest; Count: Integer);
> ```
>
> The `Move` procedure copies data from an arbitrary variable
>   into any other variable. It needs to accept sources and destinations of
>   all types, which means it cannot require any single type. The procedure
>   does not modify the value of the variable passed for `Source`, so that
>   parameter’s declaration uses `const` instead of `var`, which is the
>   more common modifier for untyped parameters.

In the case of `TStream.Read`, the source is the stream's contents, so you don't pass that in as a parameter, but the destination is the `Buffer` parameter shown in the question. You can pass any variable type you want for that parameter, but that means you need to be careful. It's *your* job, not the compiler's, to ensure that the contents of the stream really are a valid value for the type of parameter you provide.

Read the rest of my article for more situations where Delphi uses untyped parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the Delphi help for "Untyped parameters"

You can pass in any type, but you have to cast it in the implementation. Help says that you cannot pass it a numeral or untyped numeric constant. So basically you have to be know what type to expect, and compiler can not help you, so you need a good reason to do it this way. I suppose it could be of use if you need the method to handle incompatible types, but then again you could write several overloaded versions for each expected type, I would suggest that as a better solution.

Comment: The `Buffer` parameter is not a pointer. Treat it like a pointer, and things will crash. It is the *actual buffer* want to change, not a pointer to a buffer. The address of the parameter is the address of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps surprisingly, it is legal to pass a dereferenced pointer as an untyped parameter. And the pointer itself doesn't even have to have a type.

```
procedure SomeMethod(var aParameter);
  ∶

procedure CallSomeMethod(aIsInteger : Boolean);
type
  buffer    : Pointer;
  intValue  : Integer;
  realValue : Single;
begin
  if aIsInteger then
  begin
    buffer := @intValue;
  end
  else
  begin
    buffer := @realValue;
  end;
  SomeMethod(buffer^);
```

Of course it would probably have been easier if the parameter to SomeMethod() had been a pointer, but this might not be under your control.

Answer (score -1):

`var` in a parameter list is the Delphi syntax for [call by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_reference#Call_by_reference). It can be **typed** as e.g. the AllowChange parameter in the OnChanging handler of an Listview:

```
procedure TSomeForm.LVOnChanging(Sender: TObject; ...; var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin
  if SomeProblemOccurred then
    AllowChange := False;
end;
```

or **untyped** as in your example.