# Delphi, Noob Questions #2

Tags: delphi, syntax

In the following piece of code:

```
type
    TDoubleDWORD = record
    L, H: Longint;
  end;
function BitSelection(const Block: Integer; const A;
                      const ASize: Integer): Longint;
var
  H, L: Longint;
begin
  H := TDoubleDWORD(Block).H;
  L := TDoubleDWORD(Block).L;
```

My Questions Are:

1. What is the type of parameter `A`?
2. What does `TDoubleDWORD(Block)` mean? Is that some sort of constructor for the record `TDoubleDWORD`?

Sorry if the questions seem trivial, but I'm pretty new to the Delphi Programming Language and Google isn't much help.

Comment: The code seems kind of weird. It's as if the author wasn't aware of `Int64` and `UInt64`.

Comment: That code is faulty. He's casting a 32 bit value to a 64 bit long record. It will end up to access the wrong memory, it's a kind of buffer overflow (BTW Delphi has already the Int64Rec type to access parts of a 64 bit value).

Comment: Untyped parameters are pretty weird, I think of them as kind of like a "void *" in C, except that it uses reference semantics instead of pointer semantics. is "void &c" valid? I dunno. Avoid untyped parameters. YOu need to read this kind of code, to understand some old delphi code, but seeing untyped parameters is a sign that either (a) it's really old code, or (b) it's probably evil.

Comment: @Warren, It is old code , file dates to 2000 , And I think 'Block' here should be an Int64.

Comment: @Warren: Untyped parameters was a very good approach before the existence of Variants.. I heavily used that in TP days in functions like nowadays Format :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Untyped / typeless parameters in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928463/parameter-without-a-type)
2. Its a cast.

Answer (score 2):

`A` is an untyped parameter. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928463/parameter-without-a-type) is question about that with [link](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/untyped) to an article.

`TDoubleDWORD(Block)` is a typecast to `TDoubleDWORD`.